# change time in timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have some timestamps in python pandas, `Timestamp('2000-02-09 00:00:00')` and I would like to convert them to `Timestamp('2000-02-09 13:00:00')`. Just adding 13 hours wouldn't work as some of them have different time. Can you point to a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you need to replace your hours minutes and seconds from original to 13:00:00?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use replace method of pandas timestamp objects:

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.Timestamp('2000-02-09 00:00:00')
t = t.replace(hour=13, minute=0, second=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#overview) is a `datetime` subclass and therefore it has all its methods such as `.replace()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> issubclass(pd.Timestamp, datetime)
True
>>> isinstance(pd.Timestamp('2000-02-09 00:00:00'), datetime)
True
>>> pd.Timestamp('2000-02-09 00:00:00').replace(hour=13)
Timestamp('2000-02-09 13:00:00')
```